# A graph $G$ is Eulerian path iff degree of each vertex is even with atmost one NONtrivial component

Tags: graph-theory

For this proof ,proving

$\Rightarrow$ If Graph $G$ is eulerian then degree of each vertex is even with atmost one trivial component.

As $G$ is Eulerian ,it means it **must not** repeat Edges but can repeat vertices.Now for the Eulerian (path) traversal ,we pass through that vertex using two incident edges,one for entry and other for exit.

Then what is wrong [image: in this graph?]

Here we have Eulerian path traversal as

$C\rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow D \rightarrow C \rightarrow F \rightarrow E \rightarrow H \rightarrow G \rightarrow F $

but here degree of $C,F =3$ contradictory....

help me out where i am wrong

Edit 1-:Explain for eulerian path.

Edit2-:non trivial component

Comment: A circuit starts and ends at the same vertex.

Comment: i have edited my question ...what if the traversal is eulerian path..!!!

Comment: What is your definition of Eulerian graph? The definition I'm familiar with requires you to traverse each edge exactly once ***and return to the starting point.***  In your example, you start at $C$ and end at $F$. To get back to $C$ you would have to re-use the edge $CF$, or elss add another edge between $C$ and $F$ which would raise the degrees of those vertices to $4.$

Comment: By "at most one trivial component" did you mean "at most one ***nontrivial*** component?

Comment: Leave that atmost one Trivial component(take it 0 )!! theorem is simply that A graph is Eulerian iff  every vertex is of even degree !!!

Comment: Eulerian Graph is a graph containing Eulerian path  $\rightarrow$ eulerian path is path containing all edges (non repeated).Eulerian circuit contains allnon repeated edges with start and end vertex same

Comment: A Eulerian graph is usually defined as a graph having a Eulerian ***circuit***. A graph which has a Eulerian circuit, or even a Eulerian path, can have at most one nontrivial component.

Comment: Yes you are right ..!!! An eulerian gaph must have a nontrivial component!!! Let i have another edges connecting $F \rightarrow H$ .and here $H$ has degree $1$...but still degree of vertex $C$ is 3...My next Question is that do Eulerian graph necesarily contain an Eulerian Circuit? ?? it may also contain only Eulerian Path..Isn't it?

Comment: Let $G$ be a connected graph. (More generally, $G$ could be a graph with only one nontrivial component; i.e., a connected graph plus a number of isolated vertices.) Then: (1) $G$ has an Eulerian ***circuit*** if and only if $G$ has ***no*** vertices of odd degree; (2) $G$ has an Eulerian ***path*** if and only if $G$ has ***at most two*** vertices of odd degree.

Comment: okk thank you !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [@bof](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/111012/bof)'s comment:

Let $G$ be a connected graph. (More generally, $G$ could be a graph with only one nontrivial component; i.e., a connected graph plus a number of isolated vertices.) Then:
(1) $G$ has an Eulerian ***circuit*** if and only if $G$ has no vertices of odd degree;
(2) $G$ has an Eulerian ***path*** if and only if $G$ has ***at most two*** vertices of odd degree.

---

Note that "***at most two*** vertices of odd degree" means zero or two vertices, since the total of all vertex degrees is even. Also, generally, an **[Eulerian graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)** is one that has an Eulerian circuit.